# create array from string and remove formatting

Tags: java, json

```
[{"month":"1_month","title":"one","tasks":[{"task_title":"1"}]}]
```

can u help me for retrive array element from this string.

Comment: What formatting are you speaking of?

Comment: You need to parse the `JSON` for that and trust me, `JSON` parsing doesn't require formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is data in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. There are many different JSON parsers you can use to interpret data in that format easily. Here are a few to choose from:

- [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) -- as simple as they come
- [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) -- much more heavy duty
- [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) -- Google's own JSON library
- [jsonification](https://github.com/sigpwned/jsonification) -- full disclosure, this one's mine

You should be able to find good how-to's on any of these libraries. For the sake of example, if you use Jsonification from above, you'd simply use something like:

```
JsonArray  os=Json.parse("[{\"month\":\"1_month\",\"title\":\"one\",\"tasks\":[{\"task_title\":\"1\"}]}]").asArray();
JsonObject o=os.get(0).asObject();
System.out.println(o.get("month").asString().stringVal());
```

...which would extract the `"1_month"` value from the first element.